# how to set the UIImageView align left or right when set the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to control the image alignment when using the `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` in `UIImageView`.

[image]

For example, I have two `UIImageView` in one view as above.these two `UIImageView`'s contentMode is `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`. Now I want to set image 3 to align right and image 4 to align left, so that these two images can be together.

I try to set the contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspect|UIViewContentModeLeft`, but it make things worse.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally, I find [UIImageViewAligned](https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned) project which can work it out.

Thanks to @Marchy, there is also swift version [UIImageViewAlignedSwift](https://github.com/sochalewski/UIImageViewAlignedSwift)

> **Note** that some constraints need to be edited, else the image may not show.
>
> For example, the "lessThanOrEqual" constraints should be changed to "equal".

Comment: And here's a version rewritten in Swift: https://github.com/sochalewski/UIImageViewAlignedSwift

Comment: @Marchy Many thanks for the swift version. It helped me. I think you should post it as separate answer as someone might fail to go through the comment.

Comment: Swift implementation for this library
`imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
imageView.setValue("true", forKeyPath: "alignTop")`

Comment: Both libraries show very small image, they seem to apply before the constrains.

Answer (score 9):

Rather than trying to left align the image within the image view, you could programatically add a width constraint to the image view so that there is no "excess space".

Suppose you have a `UIImageView` with "Aspect Fit" content mode, and a fixed height constraint added in the interface builder. Then, in the relevant view controller, check the aspect ratio of the image and apply the necessary width constraint to snap the image view to the contained image. E.g.:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // UIImage loaded from somewhere...
    imageView.image = uiImage

    // Check the UIImageView for existing height constraints
    let heightConstraints = imageView.constraints.filter{$0.firstAttribute == .height}
    if let imageViewHeight = heightConstraints.first?.constant {

        // Calculate the width which would make the image view fit
        // the image perfectly, and constrain the view to that width.
        let desiredImageViewWidth = (imageViewHeight / uiImage.size.height) * uiImage.size.width
        imageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: desiredImageViewWidth))
    }
}
```

To apply this to your problem, you could constrain your two `UIImageView`s to be next to one another, set a fixed height constraint for both (of the same value), and then programatically set the width using the above code.

Answer (score 5):

Another option for some people might be to adjust the **Content Hugging Priority** on the `UIImageView`. In Interface Builder add a constraint to the `UIImageView` with a low priority.

[image]

This will satisfy the constraints until an image is added. Then set the UIImageView's **Content Hugging Priority** to a high value for width (or height if you are top/bottom aligning).

[image]

Then just set the UIImageView's Content Mode to what you want. Hope this helps!

Comment: That actually worked for me, with minor adjustments!

Comment: IMHO, This is the correct answer. Set a connecting constraint with a low priority and then up the content hugging priority. Works like a charm.