# iOS swift Aspect Fit left placement

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an `UIImageView` with aspect fit.

The `UIImage` is always centered in the `UIImageView`, how can i make the image placed to the left? I can't find any settings. Is there any workaround?

Comment: As far as i know, it can't be done with only UIImageView. This may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626816/how-to-set-the-uiimageview-align-left-or-right-when-set-the-contentmode-to-uivie)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/reydanro/UIImageViewAligned) is a good example using which you can achieve what you are trying to achieve.

It is a subclass of `UIImageView` that allows you to customize the alignment of the displayed image inside the `view's` frame. This works even if the `contentMode` is set to `AspectFit`, `AspectFill` or `ScaleToFill`.

Answer (score -4):

try imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;